# why exactly does delta go to the Value 1 for atm calls with a volatility converging to zero if a positive risk free rate is assumed. (bs-modell)

Tags: options, european-options

Im basically looking for a further/non mathematical explanation for following answer [ATM call option delta with low volatility](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/42854/atm-call-option-delta-with-low-volatility)
what is meant with a positive drift? does that mean we assume the stock will grow by r? could somebody please give an example how the option is in the money forward? or how my stock appreciates at r with no volatility? the only possible explanation i have is that we just assume that our stock grows by r, since our volatility is known and near zero, due to abitrage arguments our stock has to grow by r since otherwise we could just short sell and invest in r. I basically understand how this is computed mathematically in the bs formula, i just cant really grasp the concept/meaning behind it.

Comment: Yes, you got it. The BS model takes the Time Value of Money seriously, it is built into the model. Current dollars and future dollars are not the same. If the current market consensus for the stock price is $S$ (the "spot price") then the market consensus for where the price will be at T is $S e^{rT}$ (the "forward price"). So in the absence of random movements the stock price is assumed to appreciate at the rate $r$, the risk free rate. This is also called "the drift". If $S e^{rT} > K $ we say that "the stock is in the money forward", if $S>K$ we say "the stock is in the money [now]"

Comment: Note that strictly speaking comparing $S$ and $K$ is illogical: $S$ is a price paid now and $K$ is paid at maturity. You are comparing apples and oranges.  It makes more sense to compare $S$ to $PV(K)=K e^{-rT}$ or to compare $FV(S)=S e^{rt}$ to $K$. So the traditional concept of "in the money" is flawed and violates TVM.